# Studying and working in different cities in Canada

Tags: canada, working, students

In which of the following cities in Canada, it is easy to find part-time tech jobs for a CS PhD student?

1. Saint John, New Brunswick
2. Guelph, Ontario
3. Windsor, Ontario
4. Winnipeg, Manitoba

Also, please, tell me something about earning versus living expense ratio in those cities?

Comment: I believe "2.Guelph, Ontario" should be easier as the current period (2017).

Answer (score 3):

Your first place to look for this kind of information is the [Statistics Canada website](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/eng/start). For the 2006 census, it had information on employment by industry in each census metropolitan area (CMA), although I'm not sure whether it had the same in 2011. There should also be information about average wages in different CMAs, possibly per industry. If there isn't a comparison of the cost of living by CMA, the information about house prices by CMA may be available from the [Canada Mortgage and Housing Corporation](https://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/index.cfm).

Comment: Welcome to SE Expats. I think this is fine as answer, offering good direction for the OP's research. I've edited it a bit and added the links, for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage to Guelph is that even if you can't find work in the city itself, there are many high-tech opportunities in larger cities not far away.
The corridor between Toronto and Waterloo is crowded with high-tech companies ([Waterloo is Canada's Silicon Valley. Here's Why](https://www.teampintoblog.com/post/waterloo-ontario-is-canada-s-silicon-valley-here-s-why#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20Why,-Updated%3A%20May%2013&text=Waterloo%20is%20a%20small%20and,new%20startups%2C%20mainly%20tech%20businesses.)).

- Kitchener and Waterloo are 45 minutes to the west. Many tech companies within Waterloo Region actually support new startups though Communitech ([membership list](https://www.communitech.ca/communitech-members.html)). Many international companies (e.g. Google, Shopify) have a large presence here, while many other international companies *started* here (e.g. Open Text, ATS, RIM/Blackberry, Descartes).
- Mississauga is an hour east.
- Toronto is an hour and a half east.  Toronto is now the 4<sup>th</sup> largest city in North America, behind Mexico City, New York City, and Los Angeles.
- The USA border is only 1½ hours away.

The times are by car from city hall to city hall, so unless you live and work right downtown, the times could be considerably less.

And if you *do* want downtown to downtown, there are [GO Transit (Regional Public Transit Service for the GTHA)](https://www.gotransit.com/en/) trains connecting them all.